# Function pointer - cannot change function signature, what are my options?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have an example function with pseudocode

```
bool DeleteValues(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    bool isElementDeleted = false;
    if(some condition is true)
    {
        delete element from vec;
        isElementDeleted = true;
    }
    else if(some other condition is true)
    {
        delete element from vec;
        isElementDeleted = true;
    }

    return isElementDeleted;
}
```

This deletes some elements from an input vector. There are various scenarios as to why an element should be deleted and it checks for them in this function and deletes the element.
If something got deleted it returns true, else false.

This is called via a pointer call in some other function.
This is all legacy code.

The new requirement is, in addition I should also be able to get the reason why it was deleted.

Since I cannot change the function signature (which would lead to a lot of changes in other non related parts of code), what are my options?

Comment: `push_back` in the input `std::vector<int>` one `int` with the value/code of deletion.

Comment: It's good that the shown function is pseudo-code, because it would actually not remove anything from the vector. At least not from the callers perspective (hint: use *references*).

Comment: You may use some global state for that... :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 globals are a no no

Answer (score 3):

You actually *can* change the function signature, by adding a parameter with a *default value*. All the legacy code will still work, as the extra argument will have the default value, and the new code that needs the reason sent back, will pass something to the second (optional) argument.

What the extra optional argument should be? Maybe a `std::string` (or rather, a reference to one)?

---

You can also solve this by writing a second function, which actually does the work now done in the current function. This new function takes two arguments, and the first function (your current function) simply calls the new function.

This could like

```
bool DeleteValuesWithReason(std::vector<int>& vec, std::string& reason)
{
    // Code here, same as before but sets reason
}

bool DeleteValues(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    std::string dummy;
    return DeleteValuesWithReason(vec, dummy);
}
```

Comment: I want the deletion reason (which as you rightly said would be `std::string`) at the point of call of this routine. Would creating the 2nd function as you suggested work? Sorry if I missed anything.

Comment: _"This is called via a pointer call in some other function."_ if the code uses a pointer to function of type `bool (*)(std::vector<int> vec)` then adding a default argument will break the code. Also, giving a default argument to a parameter of type (non-const)  `std::string&` is awkward.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's why I added the two-function paragraph.

Comment: @ontherocks Since you in places have a pointer to the function, you can't use the variant with a single function using default arguments. Instead I have added some code to show how it could be done with two function. When you want to get the reason, you have to modify the code to use the correct function, but everywhere else it should work as before.

Comment: In a sense, do not use function pointer at all, just use the new function in my particular call...is that what I can infer?

Comment: @ontherocks If there's legacy code using function pointers, then it might be hard to change it due to different project constraints. Also, if you don't need the reason of the removal, there's no reason to call the new function. Instead, to save project time, just use the new function only in the places where you need the reason, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

One (very ugly) option is a global variable to hold the reason. Change the function to write the reason to the global, and change the caller to read the global. If the program is multithreaded then the global would have to be `thread_local` (or `__thread`) so that concurrent calls in different threads don't conflict writing to the same variable.

Comment: The caller & the function are in different source files :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a method for  the "get the reason for deleting" in the class( or where you are actually invoking this call) for e.g.

```
 std::string reasonforDeletion( pass some arguments that may 
have anything to do with the deletion)
{
// write to log file or throw a message why it's deleted. 
}
```

or if there's a base class for this you can actually overload the function signature on the child class.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an int, all int!=0 should get autocast to true.

When this is not possible maybe overload the function with a second which get a int ptr or enum in addition